# SSL on Single Instance Elastic Beanstalk, Amazon Linux 2023, Apache, PHP8

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, apache, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a few single instance environments in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. They all have SSL certificates installed via eb extensions, as opposed to using a load balancer.

They are all PHP and were running PHP 7 on Amazon Linux 1.

They are configured more or less with the guide from AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-php.html

I am trying to migrate to instances running Amazon Linux 2023 and PHP 8.2

I should note, I am using Apache, and not ngix.

So far I have changed `mod24_ssl : []` to `mod_ssl : []` and was able to get the environment to load. Regular HTTP works fine, HTTPS receives "cannot connect to server" and "connection refused" depending on the client.

My ebextensions files are as follows:

```
packages:
  yum:
    mod_ssl : []

files:
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
      Listen 443
      <VirtualHost *:443>
        <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        SSLEngine             on
        SSLCertificateFile    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"
        SSLCipherSuite        EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
        SSLProtocol           All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLHonorCipherOrder   On
        SSLSessionTickets     Off

        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
        Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
        Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:80/ retry=0
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:80/
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https" early

      </VirtualHost>

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      ~~~~~~~
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

—

```
Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Auth:
          type: "s3"
          buckets: ["elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-xxx"]
          roleName:
            "Fn::GetOptionSetting":
              Namespace: "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
              OptionName: "IamInstanceProfile"
              DefaultValue: "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
files:
  # Private key
  "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key":
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    authentication: "S3Auth"
    source: https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-xxx/xxx.pem
```

—

```
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

I have reissued the certificates, and re-rolled the environments multiple times. I have spent hours searching the web for answers with no luck. I do not see any guides for setting this up targeted at Amazon Linux 2023.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.generic.from-al1.html

> On AL2023/AL2 platforms, you can use configuration files as before, and all sections work the same way. However, specific settings might not work the same as they did on previous Amazon Linux AMI platforms. For example:
>
> - Some software packages that you install using a configuration file might not be available on AL2023/AL2, or their names might have changed.
> - Some platform specific configuration options have moved from their platform specific namespaces to different, platform agnostic namespaces.
> - Proxy configuration files provided in the .ebextensions/nginx directory should move to the .platform/nginx platform hooks directory. For details, expand the Reverse Proxy Configuration section in Extending Elastic Beanstalk Linux platforms.

Further Discussion here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

**Solution:**

Move the contents of the ssl.conf file created in the eb extension file to `.platform/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`

So the configuration is now:

—
`.ebextensions/https-instance.config`

```
  yum:
    mod_ssl : []

files:
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      ~~~~~~
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

—
`.ebextensions/https-instance-single.config`

```
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

—
`.ebextensions/privatekey.config`

```
Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Auth:
          type: "s3"
          buckets: ["elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-025310008910"]
          roleName:
            "Fn::GetOptionSetting":
              Namespace: "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
              OptionName: "IamInstanceProfile"
              DefaultValue: "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
files:
  # Private key
  "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key":
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    authentication: "S3Auth"
    source: https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-xxxxx/xxx.pem
```

—
`.platform/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  SSLEngine             on
  SSLCertificateFile    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"
  SSLCipherSuite        EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
  SSLProtocol           All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLHonorCipherOrder   On
  SSLSessionTickets     Off

  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
  Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:80/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:80/
  ProxyPreserveHost on
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https" early

</VirtualHost>
```

—

Once everything is working you should also go through and tighten up the security a bit. More here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2023.html